# Generate a variables length placement holder string for paramaterized queries in python

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'd like to build a query string with a variable length in where clause.

In PHP I might do this like

```
<?php
$vars=array('john','mike','matt');
$placeHolders=array_fill(0,sizeof($vars),'%s');
$whereClause=" name in (".join(',',$placeHolders).")";
```

Is there a concise Python translation of this in python

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd use this to create the variable strings:

```
', '.join('%s' for _ in vars)
```

That eliminates the need to substring the result and gets you as many placeholders as you have values.